# Why does the IMF insist on maintaining the privatization of state entities as a reform policy as a prerequisite for borrowing states?

Tags: economy, privatization, international-monetary-fund

Why does the IMF insist on maintaining the privatization of state entities as a reform policy as a prerequisite for borrowing states?

https://www.soas.ac.uk/cdpr/publications/papers/file24328.pdf

> Critics  have  emphasised  that  the  Washington  Consensus  greatly 
>   exaggerated  both  the  ease  of  implementing  privatisation  and 
>   the  gains  from  privatisation  (Cook  1997; Heald, 1992, cited  in 
>   Cook  and  Kirkpatrick,  1995,  22).  **And  the  World  Bank  itself 
>   has  found  that  efforts  to  encourage  privatisation  have  been 
>   among  the  most  disappointing  of  all  structural  adjustment 
>   policies  (Helleiner,  1994).    The  Post-Washington  Consensus
>   recognises that privatisation was not  well  planned:  “From  today’s 
>   vantage  point,  the  advocates  of  privatisation  may  have 
>   over-estimated  the  benefits  and  underestimated  the  costs"** 
>   (Stiglitz,  1997a,  19).  In  Stiglitz’s  view, most  people  at  the 
>   time  would  have  preferred  to  have  proper  regulatory  systems 
>   and competition  in  place  before  privatisation  but  the  reason 
>   it  was  pushed  through  was  that  “no-one  knew  how  long  the 
>   reform  window  would  stay  open”  (ibid,  20).  In  this  situation
>   privatising without the appropriate prerequisites in place “seemed a
>   reasonable gamble”.

It is well known at this point that the IMF privatization policy had a poor track record of success, yet it's still one of the keys conditional policy for countries to have access to IMF loans.

https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/06/02/did-the-imf-actually-ease-up-on-demanding-structural-adjustments-heres-what-the-data-say/

> Allowing a modicum of policy autonomy while under IMF programs has
>   been at the forefront of developing countries’ and observers’
>   criticisms for decades. Such concerns — **and the poor record of IMF
>   programs — sparked a period of widely advertised reforms to
>   conditionality over the 2000s.**

Which makes me wonder if the IMF ever publicly addressed this issue through a publication or whatever other means.

https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/06/02/did-the-imf-actually-ease-up-on-demanding-structural-adjustments-heres-what-the-data-say/

> There is a mismatch between what the IMF says and what the IMF
>   actually does. Available evidence provides little support for the
>   organization’s fundamental-transformation rhetoric. Instead, we find
>   that the scale of organizational change was both modest and
>   short-lived.
>
> At the core of the controversy are IMF-mandated structural reforms.
>   Unlike common IMF macroeconomic conditions (e.g., requiring borrowing
>   countries to balance their budgets or reduce public debt), these types
>   of policy reforms directly target market-state relations in borrowing
>   countries. **For example, they mandate the privatization of public
>   utilities or changing the competition framework.** As a result,
>   governments’ freedom to select policy instruments in dealing with
>   crises is constrained.

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect the official IMF rationale to be something other than the [Western, neoliberal] economic orthodoxy that privately run enterprises perform better? Someone can do the footwork and post the IMF's wording, but it seems a foregone conclusion what the gist of that would be...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the summary of a [recent IMF publication](https://www.imf.org/~/media/Files/Publications/DP/2019/English/RRSOECESEEEA.ashx), which is a working paper, so not the official position of the IMF, but it probably reflects it by and large given that an entire IMF department basically signs off on it...

> SOEs [state-owned enterprises] systematically underperform relative to their private sector counterparts. Statistical analysis in the paper finds that SOEs (1) generate less revenue per employee, (2) pay higher wages than private companies, and, not surprisingly, (3) are significantly less profitable. These results hold to varying degrees in every country in the [Central, Eastern, and Southeastern European] region and in every sector of the economy. A related concept of efficiency, namely total factor productivity, is also found to be lower in SOEs. The key reason for this underperformance is the inefficient use of resources, most notably labor; SOEs use too much labor for the output they produce.

Basically, this is just a reiteration of the neoliberal economic orthodoxy.

And they do look at "nonprofit-maximizing motivations for SOEs" as well, but their overall conclusion is that

> This paper finds little evidence that inefficiencies tied to state ownership can be justified by nonfinancial (social) objectives.

In even more official (and sufficiently recent) works, like those of the Independent Evaluation Office of the IMF, there is a growing emphasis is on economic growth rather than privatization (and the broader structural reforms) per se. [I think this aspect is described by others as the "cuddly IMF".] But clearly the IMF thinks the latter kind of measures imply more growth, at least in the long run... There is this implicit reference (privatization falls under "structural reforms") in the [2019 draft IEO report](https://ieo.imf.org/~/media/IEO/Files/evaluations/ongoing/ag-draft-issues-paper.ashx):

> Structural reforms are an important aspect of program design to support growth and
>   facilitate needed policy adjustments. While structural reforms would normally be expected to
>   have long-lasting impact on growth, they may take time to put in place and take effect. Reform
>   strategies also need to consider country ownership, focus, and technical support to foster
>   adequate implementation, follow-through, and impact. The 2018 ROC [review of conditionality] found that structural
>   conditionalities often did not address gaps identified in prior surveillance especially in macrostructural
>   areas outside the Fund’s core expertise. This background paper will draw on the
>   country case studies to dig deeper to assess country experiences on growth-enhancing structural
>   reforms undertaken in the context of IMF-supported programs.

Alas the full report is not yet published, so the last sentence is just a teaser for now. But do note the official phrase "growth-enhancing structural reforms"; it seems to be gist of the "cuddly" IMF. The EU has [a web page](https://ec.europa.eu/info/business-economy-euro/growth-and-investment/structural-reforms/structural-reforms-economic-growth_en) detailing what they mean by "structural reforms for economic growth"; it includes "make labour markets more adaptable and responsive" and "liberalise service sectors, boost competition in product and service markets, specific sectors, or improve the overall business environment". The IMF's interpretation of the similar phrase they employ cannot be all that different.

Comment: It is, of course, the neoliberal economic orthodoxy, but why did you specifically qualify it as Western?

Comment: @michau: it's an alternative qualification, not a sub-qualification of neoliberal (there's a comma between them).

Comment: It's a strange classification, then. It makes quite a few East Asian countries more "Western" than whole Northern Europe.

Comment: @michau: five, I've deleted that since it was non-essential. But I don't know what the prevailing economic thinking is in China, Russia or even Saudi Arabia. The governments of those countries probably do not quite agreeing with the IMF paper, at least in the final conclusion I've quoted (i.e. the tradeoff).

Comment: @michau: I don't get what's wrong with that. However French the Revolution was (it even had proto-socialists), plenty of even more revolutionary movements arose during the 20th century.

Comment: It is interesting that the three 'issues' in the first quote seem like points in favour of nationalisation. 1) make less revenue = no overcharging 2) Pay higher wages = supposed to be the point of capitalism 3) make less profit = essential services should not be profit making also see points 1 and 2 for why this should be expected.

Comment: @Jontia It's almost as if neoliberal doctrine is about profit for owner-class at expense of everyone else...

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I don't understand. What do the French Revolution, proto-socialists and 20th-century revolutionary movements have to do with qualifying the neoliberal orthodoxy as Western?

Comment: @Jontia: that's because the doctrine is that maximising total growth is the most beneficial thing to do [for society as a whole]. It often entails maximizing growth in the owner-class. https://medium.com/@russroberts/do-the-rich-capture-all-the-gains-from-economic-growth-c96d93101f9c

Comment: @Jontia: More recently the IMF has started to talk more of social protection; it might be another reason why they are called cuddly now. But they do say it's not their core concern or expertise https://ieo.imf.org/en/our-work/evaluation-reports/Completed/2017-0724-the-imf-and-social-protection

Comment: @michau: You complained about "a strange classification" that makes East Asian countries look more "western" than Northern Europe. I simply highlighted that the point you were finding strange is orthogonal, and raised that plenty of countries ended up more revolutionary than France ever was.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy If there was a "mirror" question, such as "Why do the communists insist on nationalisation of private entities?" and somebody answered, "[...] Basically, this just a reiteration of the [Western, communist] economic orthodoxy.", I would find it equally strange. Both communism and neoliberalism have their roots in the West, but nowadays they don't have much to do with the West specifically. They are global, not Western.

Comment: Re "neoliberal economic orthodoxy", if something is based on observed data, as this seems to be, is orthodoxy really the appropriate word?  If we observe that the Earth goes around the Sun, would saying so be "neo-Copernican scientific orthodoxy"?

Comment: @jamesqf Please read the question, especially the parts in bold. If the policy was based on observable data, it would have to be much more nuanced than "private good, state-owned bad".

Comment: @jamesqf: I think it is an appropriate term. It's a separate decision to consider the function to be maximized to be the total growth, ignoring for instance inequality. Also "orthodoxy" is opposed to heterodoxy in economics. It's not a derogatory term, just a statement of fact. (Likewise for neoliberal.) See my related comments addressed to Jotia.

Comment: @michau: I have read the question.  I've also read the quote at the head of this answer that starts "SOEs [state-owned enterprises] systematically underperform..."  So assuming that the authors of that study collected and analyzed the data honestly & accurately, it would seem to qualify as observation, no?  And of course the conclusion is supported by much practical  experience.

Comment: @jamesqf Your logic is circular. Authors apply dogma of neoliberal orthodoxy without any discussion or proof and obviously reach neoliberal conclusions. You claim that is proof of their dogma being right. That's mistaken at best, manipulation  at worst. Their applied criterium is "private good, public bad, exploiting good, benefits bad, social safety bad, inequality irrelevant" aka. "neoliberal orthodoxy". Where's discussion why would that hold true? What about HDI, social inequality, impact of social inequality on crime and stability of countries?

Comment: It seems very very strange to *complain* that SOEs - whose purpose is not to generate profit - generate less profit than private enterprises - whose purpose is to generate profit.

Answer (score 3):

First things first (highlight mine):

> Q. [Does the IMF advocate privatization](https://www.imf.org/external/np/exr/faq/progfaqs.htm#q9) and market liberalization in poor countries, **ignoring local conditions and adverse social consequences of such policies**?
>
> A. As part of the Fund's policy to streamline conditions within Fund-supported programs, privatization and market liberalization policies are only considered *when they are essential to restore financial stability and unlock economic growth*. The IMF relies on the World Bank and other agencies for information and expertise in these areas, and every attempt is made to take account of social conditions and prevent adverse social consequences of any policies.

#### The goal is re-starting the recipient country's economy, making it self-sustainable.

---

Here's more rationale.

The IMF is not a normal bank. A normal bank would offer you a loan in expectation of receiving an interest.

If a country already has a working economy, it may not need loans at all. For large infrastructure projects that require massive financing, a government or private businesses can simply borrow from a normal bank (with or without Sovereign guarantee), pay the interest, and that's it. No obligations that accompany IMF's grants and loans — in terms of privatization, tax structure, cost reduction, social expenses, and many more.

If, however, the country's economy is in that bad shape so it cannot service the "normal" loan, its economy needs a "kick-starting". Which, in turn, requires extremely cheap financing programme, because paying a normal interest rate would "eat up" the whole benefit of economy that is in crisis or has just resolved one.

The IMF needs to make sure that **the financing actually serves its purpose**, restoring financial stability and unlocking economic growth. So in return,

> [IMF] discusses with the country’s authorities **the policies that are most conducive to a stable and prosperous economy**, drawing on experience across its membership. Member countries may agree to publish the IMF’s assessment of their economies, with the vast majority of countries opting to do so. — [About the IMF](https://www.imf.org/external/about/howwedo.htm)

This does not necessarily include privatization, but apparently, many recent IMF-supported programs included privatization because the IMF and World Bank's analysts suggested it will serve the goal stated above.

Comment: You have my upvote for finding a more direct quote about privatization in IMF programs, but I'm amused how they predicated that with "in poor countries"... If (say) Argentina (or even Moldavia) is not deemed a poor country, then they can well insist on privatization? (Rhetorical question.)